# Duplicate results are displayed in a custom plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php

I'm building a custom plugin for a Wordpress project I'm building as it's quite a specific project, and there isn't an off the shelf plugin suitable for the task.

On one page I want to list objects from the database (which is also a custom database table) in a table. There is currently one item in the database, and I can echo this fairly easily to the page without any issue.

The problem occurs when I try to put this data in to a HTML table, so when there is more than one object in the database it can be presented properly. However, as I have said there is only one record in the database at this moment, but when I include this data in to a table it displays the same record twice.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $satrent = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT id, name FROM phones WHERE phonetype = 'satellite' AND rent = '1'", ARRAY_N);
?>
```

And for the HTML table:

```
        <?php
        foreach($satrent as $sr)
        {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><?php print $satrent[1]; ?></td>
            <td><a href="#view">View</a></td>
            <td><a href="#edit">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="#delete">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Have I missed something or done something wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is a *gernaal SQL/PHP* question, not a **WordPress-specific** question.

Comment: Well it's using Wordpress tags and it's for a Wordpress enviroment, so that would make it a Wordpress question.

Comment: You're querying *custom data* from a *custom table*. Just because you're doing it from within a WordPress Plugin doesn't make this question in any way germane to WordPress development.

Comment: It's for a plugin, thats why it's tagged as plugin development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `get_row` returns a row object (or array), not an array of row objects.

You want `$wpdb->get_results` instead. This always returns an array of row objects, event if there is only one result.

You may also wish to add an

```
   if($satrent){
    //Foreach on $satrent
  }
```

so that if no results are returned, you simply don't display the table (or display something else) rather than trying to loopi through a null object which will cause an error.

Also as Chip as pointed out in his answer: You're using `$satrent` inside your foreach loop, instead of `$sr`.

Try the following code:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $rows= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, name FROM phones WHERE phonetype = 'satellite' AND rent = '1'", ARRAY_A);
?>
```

And then loop through each rows

```
<?php  if($rows): ?>
<?php  foreach($rows as $row): ?>
      <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="#view">View</a></td>
            <td><a href="#edit">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="#delete">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>


<?php endif; ?>
```

**Edit**: See Chips answer on why you are seeing duplication. But you are seeing two rows because you are looping through each returned column: 'name' and 'id'. After making Chip's corrections you'll find the table displays a row for each column in the database - see my solution to address this.

Comment: Tried this but it still displays the two records.

Comment: Perhaps combining the two answers?

Comment: Makes no difference, it still displays the same duplicate result.

Comment: @StephenHarris feel free to incorporate my answer into yours; I can then just reference yours as the complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably here:

```
foreach($satrent as $sr)
```

...and here:

```
<td><?php print $satrent[1]; ?></td>
```

You're using `$satrent` inside your `foreach` loop, instead of `$sr`.

#### Edit

Please see @StephenHarris's answer for the complete answer, which includes this one.

Comment: I used $satrent at one point because $sr was just giving the first character of the item. So $sr[0] would give the first letter, $sr[1] the second letter etc. And changing it back to $sr doesn't make a difference to the number of records?

Comment: @mickburkejnr try $sr rather than $sr[1] and my edited answer. You need to make both changes Chip and I have suggested.

Comment: Had made the changes nothing happened. There was an issue on the dev server so the pages weren't loaded properly. Now all works with both combined answers. Thanks again!